# java - locating substrings and accounting for them

Tags: java, string, substring, bluej

I have a class "collage", and in this class the variable is an arrayliost

```
private ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

In this homework, i have to find a fragment in which it's name includes "key"
In a previous method which was similar, I had to find the number of fragments which included the sub-string key, I used this code and it appears to have worked, except I think it will just repeatedly find the first key

```
public int countKeys(String key) 
{
  int keys = 0;
  key = "keys";
  for (Fragment sm:collage){
      if (collage.indexOf(key) != -1){
          key = key + 1;
      }
    }
  return keys;   //will repeatedly find the first key?
}
```

In the other method in which I try to find just the first Fragment in which the name  includes "key" i use this code:

```
public Fragment findFragment(String key)
{
 key = "keys";
    if (collage.indexof(key) != -1){
        return collage();
    }
} //add random fragment { start at rand() index? }
```

This method however gives the error that it cannot fins the method collage() and if i remove the brackets(?) it revives the error "incompatible types"

I am rather new to java and would appreciate the help on this homework!
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't Collage() your constructor? Do you want to return a new instance of Collage if the 'keys' not found?

Comment: Maybe you want to increment keys inside the loop and not key? (`keys = keys + 1;`? Also, you probably want to check indexOf in fragment (`sm.name.indexOf("key") != -1` maybe)

Comment: collage is not a method, it is a reference to an instance of the object of class fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this -

```
int keys = 0;
key = "keys";
for (Fragment sm : collage){   
  if (sm.getName().indexOf(key) != -1){ // assuming your Fragment has a getName() method
     keys += 1;
  }
}
```

I recommend you to first read java basics before going further

`--->`   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts